# Why does my images work locally but not on my web server

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404

I have the following hierarchy:

[image]

Locally running with `npm run start` I can see both the favorite icon and header image in my React app.

However, when I upload it to my web server, both are giving me a 404 error

index.html:

```
...
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../reactpg.png" />
...
```

Header.js:

```
...
render() {
  return (
    ...
      <img className="siteLogo" src="/reactpg_menu.png" />
    ...
  )
}
```

How can I resolve the issue with path. I used CRA to start my React app.

Comment: If I were you I'd put my images under the images folder right next to components folder and don't worry about URLs

Comment: I am reading different thing in different places. Some says put images/styles in public while other places says to put it in the src folder. I am conflicted :/

Comment: Without knowing your use case it's hard to say however putting images inside src folder covers majority of them

Comment: So out images in src folder?

Comment: I'd do exactly that

Comment: Same with styles also? And then import it?

Comment: Yes. Same with styles. And make sure to import them instead of hardcoring the url

Comment: What if I have 30 images, is there any way to import the entire folder without having to import one at a time? Thanks

Comment: Well most likely there is a way but it's not a straight forward one. But again I can hardly think of a use case where you need to import multiple images at the same time

Comment: I have a product display category page where there are 10 product listing...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use **%PUBLIC_URL%** as recommended on https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder which will generate correct url for files in public directory when built for production. Also you need to build for production to deploy on production server.

Comment: When I used `%PUBLIC_URL%` it never translated to the path, it stays at `%PUBLIC_URL%`. I did run build and copied everything from the build folder over to my server. By the way, I am putting this in a sub folder which I correctly added in the package.json file.

Comment: You will need to use PUBLIC_URL only for templates like index.html. For components, try using relative path . Also did you check when you build, you have file reactpg_menu.png in build folder?

Answer (score 0):

You use ../ to go back one directory, and ./ to go forward to the next directory, so for your header.js file I believe your image path should be "../Public/reactpg.png" which may give you an access error, because if I remember right, you can not access files from a different directory (in the backwards direction) for React. For your html file however, did you also change the image name within your manifest.json? Your manifest.json file in your /Public directory should also point properly to the image.

Comment: Thanks. Is `Public` even a folder when it's in Build so maybe the path shouldn't contain `Public`? I am new to it so just curious

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CRA. For the link tag use the following.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/reactpg.png" />
```

As for the image used inside component, react tends to give warnings for fetching resources outside the *src* folder. I'd suggest keeping all images which would come inside components inside an *images* folder inside *src*.
Assuming you have an image folder inside the src folder. Try the following.

```
import menuPng from '../images/reactpg_menu.png'

<img className="siteLogo" src={menuPng} />
```

Answer (score 0):

For `link` tag in `index.html` file you can use this,

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/reactpg.png">
```

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files),

> You can import a file right in a JavaScript module. This tells Webpack to include that file in the bundle. Unlike CSS imports, importing a file gives you a string value. This value is the final path you can reference in your code, e.g. as the src attribute of an image or the href of a link to a PDF.

So you can move your images in a folder in `src` folder, and import images in `js` files,

```
import reactpg_menu from '../images/reactpg_menu.png';

<img className="siteLogo" src={reactpg_menu} />
```

**This ensures that when the project is built, Webpack will correctly move the images into the build folder, and provide us with correct paths.**

---

**Note:**

As you have deployed your build to `sub folder` on web server, you might need a `.htaccess` file, which will redirect every request to your `index.js` file and you won't get any **404** error.

Content of `.htaccess` file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|svg|woff|ttf|eot)$
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Comment: What if I have 300 images, is it still recommended to import one image at a time? How do I import images in a CSS file?

Comment: Yes you need to import one image at a time. To use image in css file you need to specify the image path like `url('../images/reactpg_menu.png')`